# Google Chrome ignores the new added ID modifications

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my Wordpress website, I had `<ul id="shelf">`
 but I needed another one so I created a `<ul id="vip-shelf">`
. In my `styles.css` file I copied the original settings of the `<ul id="shelf">` as following:

```
#vip-shelf {
    width: 980px; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
#shelf {
    width: 980px; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
```

However, whilst it looks good on both Chrome and Firefox of my laptop, the Chrome on my desktop ignores the `#vip-shelf` part of `styles.css` file. I double checked it with Inspect option of Chrome and `#vip-shelf` was **not** listed in the CSS styles. Any solutions?

Comment: Your CSS is targeting HTML IDs but you aren't providing them in your HTML.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hey there. Sorry I wrote them wrong to the question. I fixed it. I am providing IDs. That is not the problem.

Comment: Are you using a wordpress Cache plugin?

Comment: @superDiglett Installed but not active. Tried cleaning the cache for any cases though. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: @Ted I can give the related php file content and CSS codes. Site is not online right now. I took it down after the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the server is serving you the old CSS file.

If your theme is inlcuding the CSS file with`wp_enqueue_style()` function then you need to change last parameter of the function (the version param).

Try with something like this:

```
...
wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), date('YmdHis'), 'all');
..,
```

Notice the fourth param which will append current datetime as CSS version which should force the server to give you new CSS file every time. This should do the trick but it ins't the best practice. Once you are satisified with the CSS you should hardcode the version parameter.

If your theme is loading the CSS in any other way try to append date (or any other random char) to the stylesheet URL.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for answer but this isn't the case as well. I checked my website from a website that gets screenshots of how it is seen on various browsers on various OSes. All seem to work fine except for my desktop. It is very weird. It loads the `<ul id="vip-shelf">` element from the php file but doesn't load the css settings from styles.css related to that specific ID.

Comment: If it doesn't work only on your machine/browser then it must be the browser cache. Did you try accessing it with a different browser?

Comment: Yeah as I said earlier I checked my website from a website that gets screenshots of how it is seen on various browsers on various OSes. All seem to work fine except for my desktop. I made another change and it took effect. It is weird.

Comment: Never thought about adding the current date as the Version-number. i feel dumb now, smart you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache.

You can clear the cache by doing the following:

Open Chrome.
In the top right, click the Menu Chrome Menu.
Click More tools > Clear browsing data.
In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data you want to delete. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
Click Clear browsing data.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue the style through your functions.php and add a Version number to it. Change the version number if needed, so your browser (even if cached) knows there is a new version. Just like:

```
function style_with_version() {
 wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', "all");        
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_with_version' );
```